# Android : How to send data to MySQL DB without using JDBC , PHP or any other webservice?

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, jdbc

I am developing an Android application to send data to MySQL DB. I am using Apache server. I know to send data to MySQL DB using JDBC, PHP. Now the challenge is without using JDBC and other web services

```
1. can it be possible to send data. 
2. If yes, Please help me to achieve this.
3. If no, what is the solution to overcome this.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. can it be possible to send data.

Short answer: **No**, it's not possible. How would you imagine that? You need some mechanism(web service, servlets, etc.) how to recieve and send data to remote database / server. Since it's remote without "this mechanism" it's impossible to achieve your goal.

So solution is to use mentioned "mechanism". You don't have another option.