# Fetch data in Json array and send it to server

Tags: android, mysql

I am developing an android application where I am fetch all the data in j son array.
Now i want to send said Json array to MySQL database on server.

```
db.open();     
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = db.Record();    
Gson gson = new Gson();   
String jsonPesan = gson.toJson(arrayList);  
db.close();
```

Comment: Try this tutorial, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make web-service ,you can post your data to server using webservice.

[How to send data to MySQL DB without using JDBC , PHP or any other webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803789/android-how-to-send-data-to-mysql-db-without-using-jdbc-php-or-any-other-web)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON API to create a json array and then use URL Builder to send the json as a parameter to the API.

```
jsonAttriArray = new JSONArray();
                                try {
                                    if (!someInput.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                                             {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
                                        jsonObject1.put("object1", someInput.getText());

                                        jsonAttriArray.put(jsonObject1);
                                    }
                                    if (!someInput2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                                             {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
                                        jsonObject2.put("object2", someInput2.getText());

                                        jsonAttriArray.put(jsonObject2);

                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TO DO
                                }
```

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.appendQueryParameter("jsonparams", jsonAttriArray.toString());

```
 String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
```

Comment: db.open();     
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = db.Record();    
Gson gson = new Gson();   
String jsonPesan = gson.toJson(arrayList);  
db.close(); You already have the code just start a loop and insert the arrayList values in the Json array like what I did in above code and then you have the json String with you. You try first and then it it doesn't work we can look into it

Comment: Dear how to connect server and that this j son array to server database MySQL please help me

Comment: Dear Aziz reply please

Comment: Hein provided you with a tutorial link, please follow that and do everything step by step

Comment: dear this tutorials bit difficult for me pleas help me tell me step to connect with server and post data in MySQL database